# Change the content inside tabs based on selection from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selection

Is there a simple js way to dynamically fill tabbed content in a div based on the user's selection from a dropdown menu? For example, if a user selects 'option 1' than I would like 'div 1' to be displayed (all div's include same tabbed menu) and all other divs to be hidden.

[how it should work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVdkR.png)

So div 1 is working perfectly but when I switch to div 2 other part of tabbed menu stops (keep changing tabs for div 1 instead of div 2) I tried various ideas but failed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs({
    fx: {
      opacity: 'toggle'
    }
  });



  $('.tab-content').hide();
  //show the first tab content
  $('#tab-1').show();

  $('#select-box').change(function() {
    dropdown = $('#select-box').val();
    //first hide all tabs again when a new option is selected
    $('.tab-content').hide();
    //then show the tab content of whatever option value was selected
    $('#' + "tab-" + dropdown).show();

  });
});
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js?ver=1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.24/jquery-ui.js?ver=1'></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css' type='text/css' />





<div class="tab-container">

  <div class="tab-navigation">
    <select id="select-box">
      <option value="1">Option 1r</option>
      <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>


<div id="tabs" class="ui-tabs">
  <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><a href="#div1">Features</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><a href="#div2">Screenshots</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content">
    <div id="ver-1" class="group" style="display: block;">
      <div id="div1" class="content">
        <p>DIV 1 11.0.2245</p>
      </div>
      <div id="div2" class="content">
        <p>11.0.2253</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    <div id="ver-2" class="group" style="display: block;">
      <div id="div1" class="content">
        <p>DIV 1 134.44.2245</p>
      </div>
      <div id="div2" class="content">
        <p>134.44.2255</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This ain't going work, because you are using the same `id's` multiple times.

Comment: Think of #div1, #div2 and so on... ? Can u explain me a little?

Comment: The sample image doesn't clarify the question. Do you mean you want to show only div1 inside each tab when dropdown value=1, show only div2 inside each tab when dropdown value=2 ? Right now you are hiding/showing specific tabs #tab-1 #tab-2

Comment: Please can u run the code snippet... dropdown actually select tab-1 tab-2 and tabs value 1 and 2 select div1 and div2. Dunno, I'm confused.

Comment: might consider to use `Collapse` in bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/collapse/

Comment: also https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/